# How to find out the keywords in a text table with Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark. I have two tables in HDFS. One table(table 1) is a tag table,composed of some text, which could be some words or a sentence.  Another  table(table 2) has a text column. Every row could have more than one keyword in the table 1. my task is find out all the matched keywords in table 1 for the  text column in table 2, and output the keyword list for every row in table 2.

The problem is I have to iterate every row in table 2 and table 1. If I produce a big list for table 1, and use a map function for table 2. I will still have to use a loop to iterate the list in the map function. And the driver shows the  JVM memory limit error,even if the loop is not large(10 thousands time).

myTag is the tag list of table 1.

```
def ourMap(line: String, myTag: List[String]): String = {
  var ret = line
  val length = myTag.length
  for (i <- 0 to length - 1) {
    if (line.contains(myTag(i)))
      ret = ret.replaceAll(myTag(i), "_")
  }
  ret
}

val matched = result.map(b => ourMap(b, tagList))
```

Any  suggestion to finish this task? With or without Spark
Many thanks!

An example is as follows:

table1

```
row1|Spark  
row2|RDD
```

table2

```
row1| Spark is a fast and general engine. RDD supports two types of operations.  
row2| All transformations in Spark are lazy.  
row3| It is for test. I am a sentence.
```

Expected result :

```
row1| Spark,RDD  
row2| Spark
```

**MAJOR EDIT:**

The first table actually may contain sentences and not just simple keywords :

```
row1| Spark  
row2| RDD  
row3| two words  
row4| I am a sentence
```

Comment: First, looping and parallel processing are not very good friends. Second Would you please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Many thanks for your comments. I added an example.

Comment: so actually you want to keep from table 2, the keywords from table 1 for each row ?

Comment: yes, you are right.

Comment: I've provided you with an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, considering the data sample that you have provided :

```
val table1: Seq[(String, String)] = Seq(("row1", "Spark"), ("row2", "RDD"), ("row3", "Hashmap"))
val table2: Seq[String] = Seq("row1##Spark is a fast and general engine. RDD supports two types of operations.", "row2##All transformations in Spark are lazy.")
```

```
val rdd1: RDD[(String, String)] = sc.parallelize(table1)
val rdd2: RDD[(String, String)] = sc.parallelize(table2).map(_.split("##").toList).map(l => (l.head, l.tail(0))).cache
```

We'll build an inverted index of the second data table which we will join to the first table :

```
val df1: DataFrame = rdd1.toDF("key", "value")
val df2: DataFrame = rdd2.toDF("key", "text")
val df3: DataFrame = rdd2.flatMap { case (row, text) => text.trim.split( """[^\p{IsAlphabetic}]+""")
  .map(word => (word, row))
}.groupByKey.mapValues(_.toSet.toSeq).toDF("word", "index")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode

val results: RDD[(String, String)] = df3.join(df1, df1("value") === df3("word")).drop("key").drop("value").withColumn("index", explode($"index")).rdd.map {
  case r: Row => (r.getAs[String]("index"), r.getAs[String]("word"))
}.groupByKey.mapValues(i => i.toList.mkString(","))

results.take(2).foreach(println)
// (row1,Spark,RDD)
// (row2,Spark)
```

**MAJOR EDIT:**

As mentioned in the comment : The specifications of the issue changed. Keywords are no longer simple keywords, they might be sentences. In that case, this approach wouldn't work, it's a different kind of problem. One way to do it is using [**Locality-sensitive hashing (LSH)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing) algorithm for nearest neighbor search.

An implementation of this algorithm is available [here](https://github.com/soundcloud/cosine-lsh-join-spark).

The algorithm and its implementation are unfortunately too long to discuss on SO.

Comment: Thank you so much! your answer is perfect for the example.  But I am so sorry for my bad example. I forgot one important thing. The keywords could be composed of more than one word. It could even be a sentence. Sorry for my hurry bad example. Thank you again.

Comment: And how can provide you with a good answer without that missing detail ?

Comment: @hongyan a sentence isn't a keyword. And that's a whole different approach !

Comment: Sorry for you time. I modified the example.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could gather from your problem statement is that you are kind of trying to tag the data in Table 2 with the keywords which are present in Table 1. For this, instead of loading the Table1 as a list and then doing each keyword pattern matching for each row in Table2, do this :

1. Load Table1 as a hashSet.
2. Traverse the Table2 and for each word in that phrase, do a search in the above hashset. I assume the words that you shall have to search from here are less as compared to pattern matching for each keyword. Remember, search now is O(1) operation whereas pattern matching is not.
3. Also, in this process, you can also filter words like " is, are, when, if " etc as they shall never be used for tagging. So that reduces words you need to find in hashSet.
4. The hashSet can be loaded into memory(I think 10K keywords should not take more than few MBs). This variable can be shared across executors through broadcast variables.